# Delphi XE2 Datasnap TObject with TMemoryStream

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, datasnap

How to transfer TObject with TMemoryStream through datasnap?

```
TMyObject = class(TBizObject)
  FText: TMemoryStream;  <-- Content not sent
  ...
end
```

on server side

```
TServerMethods.GetMyClass(const AId: Integer): TMyObject
begin
  Result := TMyObject.find(AId);
end;
```

On client side TMyObject in correctly unmarshalled except that FText content is empty.

TMemoryStream Json content

```
"FText": {
        "type":"System.Classes.TMemoryStream",
        "id":2,
        "fields":{
            "FCapacity":16384,
            "FSize":11788,
            "FPosition":11788
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at `MarshalUnmarshal` sample project.

Comment: I have already looked that and know how to register converter for object field. The problem is, i have many objects and I need (actually want) to register TMemoryStream converter globally. Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key was to create TConverterEvent and TReverterEvent with field type *****. It was hard to find solution without having a source code.

```
procedure RegisterDatasnapConvertersAndReverters;
var
  LConverter: TConverterEvent;
  LReverter: TReverterEvent;
begin
  LConverter := TConverterEvent.Create(TMemoryStream, '*' {FIELD_ANY});
  LConverter.TypeStringConverter := function (Data: TObject): string
    var
      stream: TMemoryStream;
    begin
      stream := TMemoryStream(Data);
      stream.Position := 0;
      Result := EncodeBase64(stream.Memory, stream.Size);
    end;
  TJSONConverters.AddConverter(LConverter);

  LReverter := TReverterEvent.Create(TMemoryStream, '*' {FIELD_ANY});
  LReverter.TypeStringReverter := function(Data: string): TObject
    var
      bytes: TBytes;
    begin
      bytes := DecodeBase64(Data);
      Result := TMemoryStream.Create;
      if nil <> bytes then
        TMemoryStream(Result).WriteBuffer(bytes[0], Length(bytes));
    end;
  TJSONConverters.AddReverter(LReverter);
end;

initialization
  RegisterDatasnapConvertersAndReverters;
```